# Maven shade plugin with JDA

Tags: java, maven, discord

I was trying to make a Minecraft plugin that can send messages from minecraft to discord. I want to use JDA (Java Discord API). But I am getting an error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDABuilder
    at me.lisuu.discord.bot.Main.startBot(Main.java:26) ~[?:?]
    at me.lisuu.discord.bot.Main.onEnable(Main.java:22) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:263) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-2740d5a-890130b]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:351) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-2740d5a-890130b]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:480) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-2740d5a-890130b]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R2.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:494) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-2740d5a-890130b]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R2.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:408) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-2740d5a-890130b]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.loadWorld(MinecraftServer.java:435) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-2740d5a-890130b]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:216) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-2740d5a-890130b]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:808) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-2740d5a-890130b]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:164) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-2740d5a-890130b]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:435) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:167) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-2740d5a-890130b]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:96) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-2740d5a-890130b]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[?:?]
    ... 12 more
```

I was looking for help on forums but solution always was: `You have to use maven shadow plugin`. I don't know how to do that. I'm new to maven, so Can someone help?
This is my pom.xml file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>me.lisuu.discord.bot.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>MavenDiscordBotLisuu</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <repositories>
        <!-- This adds the Spigot Maven repository to the build -->
        <repository>
            <id>spigot-repo</id>
            <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <name>jcenter-bintray</name>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <!--This adds the Spigot API artifact to the build -->
        <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
        <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
        <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0_168</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the shade plugin's documentation?: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html

Comment: Yes, i did! It makes no sense to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>me.lisuu.discord.bot.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>MavenDiscordBotLisuu</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <repositories>
        <!-- This adds the Spigot Maven repository to the build -->
        <repository>
            <id>spigot-repo</id>
            <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <name>jcenter-bintray</name>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <!--This adds the Spigot API artifact to the build -->
            <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
            <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0_168</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>your.main.class.if.any.MainClass</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: What should I put here? My plugin main class or JDA main class?

Comment: I know nothing about minecraft plugin development - revert to documentation, maybe you need to put nothing there (and remove whole <configuration> section) - I'd suggest setting your main class there (in worst case scenario - nothing will happen :) ). Plugin is configured correctly (with or without <configuration> section), it will create uber-jar for you.

Comment: Its not working but thanks for help! And a question, do I have to put JDA to my .jar file?

Comment: maven-shade-plugin is putting JDA into your jar file :) which part of "not working" you refer to? shade plugin doesn't work for you? or the plugin itself?

Comment: My plugin doesent have any JDA files. What if I add them by hand?

Comment: Okay... I just learned more about Maven... Thanks you helped me, its working. Sorry beacuse there was no issue with your code.

Comment: I'm glad it's working - and even more importantly, you got to learn something new :) good luck!